Use decorated service instead of original service
I have a scoped HTTP client in my Symfony application.
framework:
    http_client:
        scoped_clients:
            core.client:
              base_uri: '%env(CORE_API_URL)%'

And this client is injected in service by

Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface $coreClient

I need to log a request and response and therefor I've introduced a decoration for it
// services.php
return static function (ContainerConfigurator $configurator): void {
    $services = $configurator->services();
    $services
        ->set(HttpClientLoggerService::class . '.core')
        ->class(HttpClientLoggerService::class)
        ->decorate('core.client')
        ->args(
            [
                service('.inner'),
                service('monolog.logger.core'),
            ],
        );
};

How can I now instruct Symfony to use the new decorated version instead of original service whenever I inject it with the same Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface $coreClient?

Do you use Symfony 6? I've also seen some issues with this, as the scoped clients are configured differently...

You can do it by redefining the alias for that argument as follow:
$services
    ->alias(HttpClientInterface::class.' $coreClient', HttpClientLoggerService::class.'.core');


Yeap, that helps! I've also tried to use a compiler pass and use registerAliasForArgument. Which does the same.
